Prevent keyboard layout from being changed
For some reason my keyboard layout occasionally switches to another language.
Is there a way to prevent other software from changing my keyboard layout?
I can run...
setxkbmap de

...to fix it, but it would be nice if it would just stay this way.
Linux Mint, Mate, i3wm

Do you need different keyboard layouts for different physical keyboards? If not then just remove the layouts you DON'T need.

No, I only need one. How do I remove the others?
